# Objects darker than they should be

Tags: texturing, shaders

I created a texture with a white background, however when applying it to an object it is darker than it should be. Here viewed in rendered mode in Eevee, however the same happens in cycles:

[image]

This is the shader, just directly plugging the texture into the material output, no shading:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably due to the *View Transform* of your *Color Management* being set to the default *Filmic*. If you switch that to *Standard*, and optionally choose your contrast level, you might get something closer to what you expect to see:

[image]

You might find it suprising that a color management mode which produces such a dull, flat looking image is the default one. That's a common reaction, especially if you're a relative beginner. But as you get more familiar with the ([surprisingly complex and contentious](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/filmic-as-default-is-hurting-the-experience-for-people/22283)) world of color reproduction, you might get to understand and start to appreciate its underlying logic and advantages. It's a relatively older video but *Blender Guru*'s [The Secret Ingredient to Photorealism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9AT7H4GGrA) is a nice introduction to the discussion, if you're interested.